# Ion Auth in_group() - multiple groups (by id)

Tags: php, ion-auth

There's some strange behaviour in my application regarding the Ion Auth in_group function.

My authenticated user is part of group 2. When I execute the code `$this->ion_auth->in_group(2)?'success':'fail';` the result is 'success' which is the expected result.

Passing an array like `$this->ion_auth->in_group(2,4,5)?'success':'fail';`, `$this->ion_auth->in_group(array(2,4,5))?'success':'fail';` or `$this->ion_auth->in_group($group_ids)?'success':'fail';` will always result in 'fail', which is not expected.

I can confirm that `$group_ids` is structured correctly:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 5
)
```

As [the Ion Auth documentation explains](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/#in_group): `TRUE if the user is in any of the given groups, FALSE otherwise.` **What might I be doing wrong?**

Used Ion Auth version: 2.5.2

As a current work around (I don't want hardcoded groups), I'm using `$this->ion_auth->in_group('order')?'success':'fail';` as my database is looking like this:

```
INSERT INTO user_groups(id, name, description, can_order)
VALUES(1,'admin','admin',0),
    (2,'order','internal',1),(3,'controller','controller',0),
    (4,'order','external 1',1),(5,'order','external 2',1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the latest Ion Auth code from the “2” branch in [Github](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth). There was a bug fix to the in group functionality a couple months ago, it might be related.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this (and for developing the package). Since upgrading isn't as easy in this project, I'll have to try it out later. Appreciate it!